# How can i Write My Endpoints API in Program Class in .net Core 6

Tags: webapi

I have a .net core 6 minimal web API and I want to write my endpoint (like action in Controller) in my program class,,,
How Can Use Map Function in the program class for defining API (post-get-put ....)
can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.net core 6 have good solution for that and you can use below function for your issue,,
app.MapGet
app.MapPost
app.MapPut
app.MapDelete
these function sole your problem,,
you can use this code for your program,,

    //get student by id
    app.MapGet("/getstudentbyid", async (int id, DbContextClass dbContext) =>
    {
        var student = await dbContext.student.FindAsync(id);
        if (student == null)
        {
            return Results.NotFound();
        }
        return Results.Ok(student);
    });
    
    //create a new student
    app.MapPost("/createstudent", async (Product product, DbContextClass dbContext) =>
    {
        var result = dbContext.student.Add(student);
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Results.Ok(result.Entity);
    });
    
    //update the student
    app.MapPut("/updatestudent", async (student student, DbContextClass dbContext) =>
    {
        var studentDetail = await dbContext.student.FindAsync(student.studentId);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return Results.NotFound();
        }
        studentDetail.studentName = student.ProductName;
        studentDetail.studentDescription = student.ProductDescription;
        studentDetail.studentPrice = student.ProductPrice;
        studentDetail.studentStock = student.ProductStock;
    
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Results.Ok(studentDetail);
    });
    
    //delete the student by id
    app.MapDelete("/deletestudent/{id}", async (int id, DbContextClass dbContext) =>
    {
        var student = await dbContext.Product.FindAsync(id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return Results.NoContent();
        }
        dbContext.student.Remove(product);
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Results.Ok();
    });
    
    app.Run();
```

Comment: the code is work for me